# Can I disable a filter conditionally in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am applying filter based on whether a record is active or not. There are basically three things 
1)show all record
2)show active ones
3)show only those which are inactive

I can easily apply filtering for active or inactive using following code

```
<div  ng-repeat="payhead in payHeadsList | filter:search">


<div style="float:left;width:65%" class="">
                <span style="float:left;" class="BodyTxt3 ML1">Show</span> 
                <select
                class="W2_Normal BodyTxt3 V4 ML1" style='float:left' id="selectPayHead"
                ng-model="search.ph_active"
                ng-options="a.value as a.name for a in payHeadOption"></select>
                </span>
 </div>


$scope.payHeadOption=[{name:"All Payhead",value:3},{name:"Active Payhead",value:1},{name:"Inactive Payhead",value:0}];
```

so on selecting Active Payhead/Inactive Payhead ,it filters out record with search.ph_active=0 or 1.
But I need to show all records on selection of All Payhead. What is the way here?

Comment: would `{name:"All Payhead",value:null}` do the trick?

Comment: @maurycy tried it,but sadly it too filter outs all records.

Comment: what about empty value? `value:''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an empty string it's like you don't specify filter criteria at all so all elements are shown, my first thought was to use `null` but it looks like `null` would be an actual value to compare while empty string match all elements

```
{name:"All Payhead",value:''}
```

Comment: so do you mean if we put null as value then it will check for those elements which have "null" as specified property???

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant